# Trying to install hlint by stack got "same package name" error

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to install hlint through stack in haskell `stack install hlint`, but it advised me that the plan failed and I should add some extra-deps in `stack.yaml`.

After i did that (and set `allow-newer: true` in config.yaml) , it returned to me the following:

```
    The same package name is used in multiple local packages

time used in:
- PLImmutable (PLIHackage (PackageIdentifier {pkgName = PackageName "time", pkgVersion = mkVersion [1,10]}) 536801b30aa2ce66da07cb19847827662650907efb2af4c8bef0a6276445075f,5738 (TreeKey 1591d9d1034f19cd38fbda525969f805b5ca083b45da85602cf2b04c1a82f640,6693))
- PLImmutable (PLIHackage (PackageIdentifier {pkgName = PackageName "time", pkgVersion = mkVersion [1,11,1,2]}) a957467595420495c2dd440d9efa1f58c62277cf9438c7e7a515d7a4c65571ec,6287 (TreeKey b7025dd19573d4c082d072eaba093a3fc1f891f3fde09b59561bcdca3566a0a4,7048))
```

I don't know how to make it right, since the cmd didn't gave me any new instructions. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing things with the global `stack.yaml`/`config.yaml` can be tricky. It's often better to clone the package repo and build it using its own config files, which specify the package's preferred Stack resolver etc. Try this:

```sh
git clone git@github.com:ndmitchell/hlint.git
# Or: git clone https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint.git

cd hlint
git checkout v3.3.1 # Latest available release
stack install
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tom. I'm new at haskell and using the cmd terminal, so I have a few more questions about your proposed solution:  1. I did the first line of the code u sent me. Here's what the cmd showed: `Cloning into 'hlint'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: Oh, I assumed you had an SSH key configured with GitHub. I just edited the solution with an alternative command you can use instead.

Comment: Thanks Tom, really. I did that and the cmd completed 60 actions and it finished. But.. does that means that hlint has been installed? I did comand `stack install hlint` again and it showed the same error as before.... If hlint is installed, shouldn't the cmd show me that it's already installed?

Comment: Sounds like it installed successfully. There's no need to try doing the global install command again since that would just run into the same problems. Try typing `which hlint` to see where it was installed; for me it's `~/.local/bin/hlint`. BTW I'd recommend undoing any changes you made to the global config like `allow-newer: true`; it's almost never a good idea to touch those unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Well, I just went into VSCode and the error message about hlint isn't showing up anymore, so yeah, the install was succesful. Can't thank you enough! I've undone any changes to both files. Thanks for the advice. About this which `hlint command`, should I run any command before it? Because the cmd says it doesn't recognize which.

Comment: Oh, you must not have `which`. That's fine, you can also just type `hlint` and confirm that it runs and shows the `hlint` options.

Comment: If everything's working then please mark the answer as accepted :)